# AWS terraform deploy Cognito User with Workteam assignment: 400 ResourceNotFound

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-cognito

I am trying to deploy an AWS Cognito user account to a team in a private workforce, which I create from .tf code. The code produces no errors during 'plan/apply' and resources are created.

When checking the workteam, I see a 400 ResourceNotFoundException (see screenshot). The workteam is created. The user is created too (also shows up in the user pool) but the assignment failed and the workteam is somewhat broken. I cannot manually assign a user to the created workteam either via frontend due to this 400 Resource-error.

Tainting the resources and forcing re-creation does not change the outcome. I found no other clues on the web what is incorrect.

terraform: 1.4.2

Does anyone has a pointer for me?
My .tf code:

```hcl
resource "aws_sagemaker_workforce" "my_workforce" {
  workforce_name = "workforce"

  cognito_config {
    client_id = aws_cognito_user_pool_client.my_user_pool_client.id
    user_pool = aws_cognito_user_pool_domain.my_user_pool_domain.user_pool_id
  }
}

resource "aws_cognito_user_pool" "my_workflow_cognition_user_pool" {
  name = "my-user-pool"
}

resource "aws_cognito_user_pool_client" "my_user_pool_client" {
  name                                 = "my-user-pool-client"
  generate_secret                      = true
  user_pool_id                         = aws_cognito_user_pool.my_workflow_cognition_user_pool.id
  allowed_oauth_flows_user_pool_client = true
  supported_identity_providers         = ["COGNITO"]
  allowed_oauth_flows                  = ["code"]
  allowed_oauth_scopes                 = ["aws.cognito.signin.user.admin", "openid"]

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = false
    ignore_changes = [
      callback_urls, logout_urls
    ]
  }
}

resource "aws_cognito_user_pool_domain" "my_user_pool_domain" {
  domain       = "my-domain"
  user_pool_id = aws_cognito_user_pool.my_workflow_cognition_user_pool.id
}

resource "aws_cognito_user_group" "my_user_group" {
  name         = "my-user-group"
  user_pool_id = aws_cognito_user_pool.my_workflow_cognition_user_pool.id
  description  = "..."
  precedence   = 42
  role_arn     = aws_iam_role.es-cognito.arn
}

resource "aws_sagemaker_workteam" "my_workteam" {
  workteam_name  = "my-workteam"
  workforce_name = aws_sagemaker_workforce.my_workforce.id
  description    = "The workteam which is assigned to a worflow"

  member_definition {
    cognito_member_definition {
      client_id  = aws_cognito_user_pool_client.my_user_pool_client.id
      user_pool  = aws_cognito_user_pool_domain.my_user_pool_domain.user_pool_id
      user_group = aws_cognito_user_group.my_user_group.id
    }
  }
}


resource "aws_cognito_user" "my_user_1" {
  user_pool_id = aws_cognito_user_pool.my_workflow_cognition_user_pool.id
  username     = "myuserxxxxx"
  attributes = {
    email          = "bla@blub.com"
    email_verified = true
  }
}


resource "aws_cognito_user_in_group" "my_assign_user_to_group_1" {
  user_pool_id = aws_cognito_user_pool.my_workflow_cognition_user_pool.id
  group_name   = aws_cognito_user_group.my_user_group.name
  username     = aws_cognito_user.my_user_1.username
}
```

[image]